# How to extract and use a string value returned from cy.wrap()

Tags: javascript, cypress

Cypress sees my returned strings as objects, so I'm trying to use cy.wrap() to resolve the value as string.

I have a cypress custom command, like so:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('emailAddress', () => {
    var emailAddress = 'testEmail-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16) + '@mail.com';
    return cy.wrap(emailAddress);
})
```

That I need the return value as a sting in my test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        var user = cy.emailAddress().then(value => cy.log(value)); // testEmail-123@mail.com
        logonView.login(user) // object{5}
      })
```

How do I use the string value for my login and elsewhere in my test?

Something like: `logonView.login(user.value)`
...  but this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cypress, you [cannot return value](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values) like this

```js
var user = cy.emailAddress().then(value => cy.log(value));
```

Instead, you get the return value in the then `.then` callback:

```js
cy.emailAddress().then((value) => {
  logonView.login(user)
});
```

So, for you test, you can instead do the following:

```js
describe("My test", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.emailAddress().then((value) => {
      logonView.login(user)
    });
  });

  it("should have logged into the App", () => {
    // Write your test here
  });
});
```

Or use a variable in the before each block, and access it later in the test:

```js
describe("element-one", () => {
  let user;

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.emailAddress().then((value) => (user = value));
  });

  it("it should have user value", () => {
    expect(user).to.includes("testEmail");
  });
});
```

Comment: I've asked a similar question here when using from cy.task(), maybe you know this issue too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130138/cypressio-returning-string-value-from-cy-task-using-cy-wrap-gives-error-cy

Comment: I will give that a look when I am free :) If you think this answer answers your question, could you please mark it as accepted? Thanks