# CypressIO Returning string value from cy.task() using cy.wrap() gives error "cy is not defined"

Tags: javascript, cypress

In cypress `/plugins/index.js` I have code to query oracleDB

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {

  on('task', {
    'registration': async (email) => {

      const oracledb = require('oracledb');

      oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: './oracleClient'});

        let result;
        let connection;

        connection = await oracledb.getConnection(  {
            user          : process.env.ORACLEDB_USER,
            password      : process.env.ORACLEDB_PASSWORD,
            connectString : "localhost/STORE"
            });

        result = await connection.execute(
            "select ..."
            );
        
        console.log(result.rows)

        var extractedUrlText = JSON.stringify((await result).rows).extract('/VerifiedRegistrationFormView','\"');
        console.log('Extracted URL: \r\n' + extractedUrlText);

      return cy.wrap(extractedUrlText);
    }
  });
}
```

This returns the correct extracted URL in Node terminal.

But then in my cypress test, when I try to use that extractedUrlText string value i'm getting error `cy is not defined`:

```
it('Register a new user', () => {

 cy.task('registration', emailAddress, { timeout: 10000 }).then(value => cy.log(value)) // cy is not defined

    })
```

I use a similiar approach to use a returned value from `support/commands.js Cypress.Commands.add()` and it works there, but not from cy.task() using cy.wrap()

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My working solution:

`/plugins/index.js` extended from above code:

```
 var extractedUrlText = JSON.stringify((await result).rows).extract('/VerifiedRegistrationFormView','\"');
    console.log('Extracted NODE URL: \r\n' + extractedUrlText);

  return extractedUrlText
}
```

In spec file:

```
let extractedUrl;

        cy.task('registration', emailAddress).then(value => {
            extractedUrl = value;
            cy.log('Extracted CY URL: ' + extractedUrl)
        })
```

Result:
[image]